# Error tracebacks with gruntjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

When encountering an error running grunt, I sometimes get messages like this, with no further information as to *where* the `data` variable was not defined, etc.

```
Running "render-site:dev" (render-site) task
Warning: data is not defined Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Is there a way to show a traceback, or even just the line number at which the error occurred?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it:

```
grunt --stack
```

.......

Comment: This literally took me 2 hours to find. If grunt was a real thing, I would throw it out the window to teach it a lesson.